# Swapping the image used for my character, to a seperate image on button click

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, events

So first off i'd like to state that i am not very good at AS3, i'm completely self taught so i am sure that there are many things i've done badly, inefficiently or plain wrong and i'm happy for any comments on these if there is things i can improve.

Okay so, this seems like a really simple problem but i don't know the exact code for it and i can't find an example anywhere

what i want to do is to change the image which i am using for my character to a separate image on a button click, then after a certain amount of time for him to go back to the original.

My image is set as a movie clip and i am calling it like so :

```
public var Smallclock_hero = new Smallclock;
```

it is worth noting that smallclock has it's own separate class.

is there a way that i can change this image on a mouse click event ?

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be:

1. Add a new image on the second frame of the Smallclock movieclip. Have this new image span several frames of the timeline for the duration you want it to appear for.
2. Place a `stop();` action on the first frame of the Smallclock movieclip.

`btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btnChangeCharacterFrame);`

```
function btnChangeCharacterFrame(e:MouseEvent)
{
  Smallclock_hero.gotoAndPlay(2);
  // Or use a frame label
  // Smallclock_hero.gotoAndPlay("jump");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved relatively simply using the visible property and setTimeout. When you click on your MovieClip you'll want to make the old image invisible and the new image visible:

```
oldImage.visible = false;
newImage.visible = true;
```

Then you'll want to use setTimeout to change the visible properties back to:

```
oldImage.visible = true;
newImage.visible = false;
```

setTimeout can run a function after a specified number of milliseconds. Here is an example of this technique on wonderfl : http://wonderfl.net/c/acxl

```
    private var imageA:ImageA = new ImageA();
    private var imageB:ImageB = new ImageB();
    private var revertId:int;

    public function Main() {
        imageB.visible = false;
        addChild(imageA);
        addChild(imageB);
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
    }

    private function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void{
          clearTimeout(revertId);
          revertId = setTimeout(revert, 1000);
          imageB.visible = true;
          imageA.visible = false;
    }

    private function revert():void{
      imageB.visible = false;
      imageA.visible = true;    
    }
```